# How can I get a report to show when contacts were added to a Group?

Tags: civireport

I have a profile that assigns contacts to a Group so I can later identify those contacts for reporting purposes.

However, I'd really like to get a report includes the date that they were added to the Group.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Subscription report extension](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/org.cpehn.subscriptionhistory) to list the contact added in a group

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I installed it on my civi 5.42.1 instance, but the report doesn't appear in the Create New Report from Template page :-(
It does appear as installed on the Extensions page...